# Is requests in IIS httppipeline processed serially?

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7, tomcat

Based on iis architecture, request from client hitting IIS will pass through httppipeline, specifically through each httpmodule and finally reaches respective httphandlers and then to worker process. Is this happening serially, one after the other?

Say if 10,000 requests hits the webserver concurrently in a sec, is each request get processed one by one? If the webserver has multi-core CPU and high memory capacity, does this helps IIS to handle the requests simultaneously?

Is there any webserver capable to handle requests in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Good question :)  You'd need a decent box to handle 10k requests per sec, in the IIS architecture to handle this type of load, you'd want a web-farm of boxes.  http.sys > Process Activation Service > w3wp is the path a request takes.  Each app pool has queues to process requests at a time.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article821-beginners-guide-how-iis-process-aspnet-request.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx

IIS 8 has NUMA support, this helps with scaling. 
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-multicore-scaling-on-numa-hardware

There are other factors, which type of content and application. :)

Comment: This does not answer the main question.  is each request get processed one by one?